# Cannot Open VBA code on Excel Mac 2011

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to open VBA code in Excel Mac 2011 that was written with Excel 2010 on a Windows computer.

I can see all modules on my Mac but I only see a blank white window when I click on a module top open it. The file(s) works perfectly under Windows Excel 2010.

Any idea how I can access the modules and the code on the Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m having the exact same problem. I´ve noticed that this only happens when you add modules to your project, so what I´ve been doing to get around this problem is writing the code as an object (for example, in Plan1).

This also allows me to edit the code, which for some reason does not happen when I use the modules.

I know this is not the ideal solution, but that´s the way I´ve found to work for now.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly VBA isn't supported in the Mac version of office. At least the 2011 version. 
I'd try checking out the latest version or running windows in emulation, perhaps.

Comment: VBA is supported in the Mac Office 2011 version and I have already used it a few times with no errors etc. I just cannot open code that was written on Mac for Windows. The file that I am referring to has 5 Modules, I can access the code of one module. When I try to open the others I get a blank window...